# Примеры записи аннотаций @OneToMany @OneToOne @ManyToMany @ManyToOne [Hibernate]

Tags: hibernate, jpa, аннотации

Интересуют как создавать сущности с аннотациями:

- `@OneToOne`
- `@OneToMany`
- `@ManyToOne`
- `@ManyToMany`

Так же вариации с `bidirectional` и `unidirectional`

Так же было бы неплохо добавить объяснений типо `Cascade.**`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Данный ответ будет модифицироваться по мере получения нужных знаний*

За основу ответа взяты примеры с данного ресурса - [How to synchronize bidirectional entity associations with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/). Данный ресурс был обновлен 19 января 2020, поэтому в случае вопросов/проблем с ответами, представленными ниже, почитайте данный вебсайт

#### Update№3 26.05.2020

1. Не используйте `@Data`, `@EqualsAndHashcode` от Lombok!! О данных проблемах написано в следующих источниках:
   [Item 45: Why Avoid Lombok @EqualsAndHashCode in Entities](https://dzone.com/articles/best-performance-practices-for-hibernate-5-and-spr)
   [The best way to implement equals, hashCode, and toString with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-implement-equals-hashcode-and-tostring-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)
   [Ultimate Guide to Implementing equals() and hashCode() with Hibernate](http://Ultimate%20Guide%20to%20Implementing%20equals()%20and%20hashCode()%20with%20Hibernate)
   Вместо этого можете  использовать `@Setter` и `@Getter`
2. Не используйте GenerationStrategy `AUTO` для ID. [Читать тут](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-should-not-use-the-auto-jpa-generationtype-with-mysql-and-hibernate/)

#### Update№2 02.02.2020

1. **ВАЖНО** Лучше **не стоит использовать** `Set<..>` вместо `List<..>` при работе с `..Many..`. Очень много проблем возникает, особенно при работе с формами. Так же прочтите данную статью одного из главных контрибьютеров проекта Hibernate - [The best way to fix the Hibernate MultipleBagFetchException](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-multiplebagfetchexception/) (Это дополнение к **Update№1 (пункт 1)**)

#### Update№1 11.09.2019:

1. Вместо `List<>` **используйте где возможно `Set<>`**. (Нет, лучше не стоит. Читать об этом в обновлении ниже)

   `Set<..>` лучше использовать вместо `List<...>`иначе при работе с `join fetch` (кастомном hql-запросе) у вас будет выпадать ошибка:
   `org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple Bags:`

   Более подробно об ошибке [написано тут](https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-how-to-avoid-hibernates-multiplebagfetchexception/)
2. **Не используйте CascadeType.ALL**

   Если кратко - лучше использовать только с `@OneToOne`, т.к. при использовании со множественными связями могут удалиться ненужные записи из бд.

   Данный момент подробно описан [в данном источнике](https://thoughts-on-java.org/avoid-cascadetype-delete-many-assocations/)

---

### GITHUB Demo  (Spring 5)

Все ниже приведенные примеры я подробно показываю в своем мини-проекте, который можно [скачать с GitHub](https://github.com/Antonio112009/HibernateAnnotationsExamples)

О каскадировании можно [почитать тут](https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-jpa-cascade-types/)

### Project Lombok

В моих ответах я использую аннотации [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/):
- [@Data](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) - Аннотация, которая добавляет в ваш проект Getters/Setters, Equals, ToString, HashCode
- [@AllArgsConstructor](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor) - Конструктор, содержащий все глобальные переменные, записанные в данном классе
- [@NoArgsConstructor](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor) - Пустой конструктор. Если мы не хотим в самом конструкторе прописывать данные, а использовать Setter
- [@ToString(exclude - "НазваниеПеременной")](https://projectlombok.org/features/ToString) - При работе с `bidirectional` у нас будет зацикливаться объекты. Чтобы этого не допустить - надо от них избавиться
[Другие аннотации Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/all)
[Установка плагина Project Lombok в IntelliJ и Eclipse](https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-ide)

---

## @OneToOne

### Вариант `unidirectional`:

> *От Пользователя к Покупателю, но не от Покупателя к Пользователю*

#### User.java:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String username;

    //Some code

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", unique = true)
    private Customer customer;
}
```

#### Customer.java

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "country_id")
    private long id;

    //Some code

    @Column(name = "customer_name")
    private String customerName;


}
```

### Вариант `bidirectional`:

> *От Пользователя к Покупателю и от Покупателя к Пользователю*

---

## @OneToMany

### Вариант `unidirectional`:

> *У Поста есть несколько Комментариев, но нам не нужно от Комментария искать Пост*

#### Post.java:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "post_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String postHeader;

    @OneToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addComment(Comment comment) {
        comments.add(comment);
    }

    public void removeComment(Comment comment) {
        comments.remove(comment);
    }
}
```

#### Comment.java:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "postcom_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String text;
}
```

### Вариант `bidirectional`:

> *Профессор на курсе может узнавать информацию о студентах, в тоже самое время студенты могут узнавать информацию о Профессоре *

#### Professor.java:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class Professor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "professor_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "professor",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

    /*
    As you see we need to do something like "recursion" below
     */
    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        students.add(student);
        student.setProfessor(this);
    }

    public void removeStudent(Student student) {
        students.remove(student);
        student.setProfessor(null);
    }
}
```

#### Student.java

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "student_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="professor_id")
    private Professor professor;

}
```

---

## @ManyToOne

---

## @ManyToMany

### Вариант `unidirectional`:

> *Пользователь может иметь несколько Ролей, Роль могут быть присвоина нескольким Пользователям*

#### User.java

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private long id;

    ...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addRoles(Role role) {
        roles.add(role);
    }

    public void removeRoles(Role role) {
        roles.remove(role);
    }
}
```

#### Role.java

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;
}
```

### Вариант `bidirectional`:

> *Трейдер может торговать на нескольких Биржах, Биржы могут посещаться несколькими Трейдерами*

#### Trader.java:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class Trader {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "trader_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "trader_name")
    private String traderName;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    @JoinTable(name = "trader_stockmarket",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "trader_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "stockmarket_id") })
    private List<Stockmarket> stockmarkets = new ArrayList<>();


    /*
    We need to add methods below to make everything work correctly
     */

    public void addStockmarket(Stockmarket stockmarket) {
        stockmarkets.add(stockmarket);
        stockmarket.getTraders().add(this);
    }

    public void removeStockmarket(Stockmarket stockmarket) {
        stockmarkets.remove(stockmarket);
        stockmarket.getTraders().remove(this);
    }

}
```

#### Stockmarket.java

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class Stockmarket{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "stockmarket_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "stockmarket_name")
    private String stockmarketName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="stockmarkets")
    private List<Trader> traders = new ArrayList<>();

    /*
    We need to add methods below to make everything work correctly
     */

    public void addTrader(Trader trader) {
        traders.add(trader);
        trader.getStockmarkets().add(this);
    }

    public void removeTrader(Trader trader) {
        traders.remove(trader);
        trader.getStockmarkets().remove(this);
    }

}
```