# Не работает сохранение при bidirectional @ManyToMany

Tags: spring, hibernate, аннотации

У меня есть две сущности:
- `Trader.java`
- `Stockmarket.java`

Я использую аннотацию @ManyToMany и у меня работает сохранение Trader, внутри которого содержится список Stockmarket, но не работает сохранение Stockmarket, в котором есть список трейдеров.

#### Trader.java

```java
import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "trader")
public class Trader {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "trader_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "trader_name")
    private String traderName;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "TRADER_STOCKMARKET",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "trader_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "stockmarket_id") })
    private List<Stockmarket> stockmarket;

}
```

#### Stockmarket.java

```java
import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "stockmarket")
public class Stockmarket{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "stockmarket_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "stockmarket_name")
    private String stockmarketName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="stockmarket")
    private List<Trader> traders;

}
```

#### Контроллер:

(В MySQL уже есть 2 трейдера и 2 биржи.)

```java
            Stockmarket stockmarket3 = new Stockmarket();
            stockmarket3.setStockmarketName("Marvel");
            List<Trader> allTraders = manyToManyBiService.findAllTraders();

            System.out.println("\n\n\n finally " + allTraders.toString() + "\n\n\n ");
            stockmarket3.setTraders(allTraders);

            manyToManyBiService.saveStockmarket(stockmarket3);
```

### Дополнительные вещи, если помогут в решении проблемы

#### ManyToManyBiService.java:

```java
@Service
public class ManyToManyBiService {

    @Autowired
    StockmarketRepository stockmarketRepository;

    @Autowired
    TraderRepository traderRepository;

    public void saveTrader(Trader trader){
        traderRepository.save(trader);
    }

    public void saveStockmarket(Stockmarket stockmarket){
        stockmarketRepository.save(stockmarket);
    }

    public Stockmarket findByNameStockmarket(String name){
        return stockmarketRepository.findByStockmarketName(name);
    }

    public List<Stockmarket> findAllStockmarket(){
        return stockmarketRepository.findAll();
    }

    public List<Trader> findAllTraders(){
        return traderRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

StockmarketRepository и TraderRepository - Это интерфей, которые extend CrudRepository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ найден.

[Полный разбор аннотаций в Hibernate](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/993199/275232)

Ошибка заключается в том, что я клал один объект в другой, но забывал ссылать вложенный объект на объект, в который он вложен.

грубо говоря у меня было так A->B->null, а надо A->B->A, чтобы получилось:
A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A... loop.

В итоге мои сущности должны выглядить вот так:

#### Trader.java

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@ToString(exclude = "stockmarkets")
@Table(name = "trader")
public class Trader {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "trader_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "trader_name")
    private String traderName;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {
        CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    @JoinTable(name = "TRADER_STOCKMARKET",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "trader_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "stockmarket_id") })
    private Set<Stockmarket> stockmarkets = new HashSet<>();


    /*
    We need to add methods below to make everything work correctly
     */

    public void addStockmarket(Stockmarket stockmarket) {
        stockmarkets.add(stockmarket);
        stockmarket.getTraders().add(this);
    }

    public void removeStockmarket(Stockmarket stockmarket) {
        stockmarkets.remove(stockmarket);
        stockmarket.getTraders().remove(this);
    }

}
```

#### Stockmarket.java:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@ToString(exclude = "traders")
@Table(name = "stockmarket")
public class Stockmarket{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "stockmarket_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "stockmarket_name")
    private String stockmarketName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="stockmarkets")
    private Set<Trader> traders = new HashSet<>();

    /*
    We need to add methods below to make everything work correctly
     */

    public void addTrader(Trader trader) {
        traders.add(trader);
        trader.getStockmarkets().add(this);
    }

    public void removeTrader(Trader trader) {
        traders.remove(trader);
        trader.getStockmarkets().remove(this);
    }

}
```

### Update 1:

В случае, если будут проблемы с `Set<>`, то используйте `List<> .... = new ArrayList<>();`,

Comment: не сработало в моём случае. Помогло вместо @ManyToMany(mappedBy="stockmarkets") поставить @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(...). Как в статье http://java-online.ru/hibernate-entities.xhtml

Comment: @MaxLich то есть вы два раза продублировали один и тот же код? Ибо `CascadeType.ALL` и `@JoinTable` я написал в `trader.java`

Comment: @MaxLich я уверен, что у вас допущена ошибка. Рассмотрите лучше [вот эту ссылку](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/). Это сайт одного из разработчиков Hibernate.

Comment: нет, не два раза один и тот. Просто зеркально отобразил этот блок кода (аннотаций)

Comment: @MaxLich честно, звучит это странно) Просто поменять местами, чтобы сработало

Comment: Я до конца не углублялся в эти аннотации, но я воспринимаю связи между объектами как "parent" и "child". В parent описываются важные зависимости по отношению к "child",  а в "child", если зависимость "bidirectional" просто указывается ссылка на родителя. Таким образом описывать основной объект "child", а второстепенный - "parent" - это уже звучит неправильно

Comment: а если нет основного объекта? если оба равноправны?