# Как построить таблицу БД на Spring+Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Требуется сделать web-приложение что-то вроде проводника
Как сделать связь родителя и ребенка?

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "directory")
    public class Directory {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
        private String name;
        private String parent;
        private String child;
```

Подумал о таком коде, но понял, что не смогу его реализовать, т.к у ребенка тоже может быть ребенок. Как быть?

Способ 2:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT")
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Child> child = new HashSet<Child>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name="CHILD")
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_ID")
    private Parent parent;
}
```

Comment: я бы сделал класс Directory и в этом классе List<Directory> subDirectories (потому что у директории может быть >1 чайлда). На какой СУБД вы это реализовываете ?

Comment: Здравствуйте,использую MySQL

Comment: Лучше бы конечно какую-нибудь, чтобы была как JSON (например, MongoDB). Ну да ладно. Я бы сделал 2 таблицы: 1. directories, 2. directories_rel (от слова relation). в первой хранил бы сами директории (id + какую-нибудь информацию о них), во второй хранил бы parent_id и child_id.

Comment: Что касается организации entity, то с помощью соответствующих аннотаци можно собрать subDirectories. Уверен, что и parent можно найти

Comment: сам не очень люблю, когда кидают доку, т. к. лень искать))) Но в даном случае вы 100% найдете здесь нужные аннотации -> https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/

Comment: скажите,а такой способ подойдет?                                                                  https://ibb.co/L10Gyy8
https://ibb.co/LhJMfhs

Comment: У меня там ничего не грузится

Comment: добавил в пост как способ 2

Comment: Рассмотрите один из вариантов тут — https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/993199/275232

Comment: 2ой способ имеет место быть, но я бы хранил все 1им классом, где есть и список детей и родитель

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы)