# Spring. Как связать две таблицы по ID

Tags: java, sql, spring, intellij-idea, spring-jpa

Пытался связать поле одной таблицы с id другой. Пока не до конца понимаю как это вообще сделать. Можно ли в spring'е реализовать первичный ключ одной таблицы, первичным ключом другой?

Т.к. у меня ни чего не получалось, я уже пытался хоть как-то связать эти таблицы...я в принципе понимаю что так не делается, но как реализовать по другому не соображу.

```java
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table
public class StatusModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @OneToOne(optional = false, mappedBy = "status_id")
    private Long id;

    private Integer lastStatus;
    private Integer cerrentStatus;

    public StatusModel() {

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setLastStatus(Integer lastStatus) {
        this.lastStatus = lastStatus;
    }

    public Integer getCerrentStatus() {
        return cerrentStatus;
    }

    public void setCerrentStatus(Integer cerrentStatus) {
        this.cerrentStatus = cerrentStatus;
    }
}
```

```java
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table
public class UsersModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "status_id")
    private StatusModel status;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    public UsersModel () {}

    public UsersModel (UsersModel usersModel) {
        this.id = usersModel.getId();
        this.status = usersModel.getStatus();
        this.name = usersModel.getName();       
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public StatusModel getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(StatusModel status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   
}
```

P.S. Спринг изучаю буквально 3 день, сильно помидорами не закидывайте.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону аннотации @MapsId.

Comment: Рассмотрите данный вопрос и ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/993198/275232

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://internetka.in.ua/hibernate-one-to-one/
Надо выбрать один из 3 вариантов, у вас 2й вариант

Аннотация не над тем полем

```
@OneToOne(optional = false, mappedBy = "status_id")
    private Long id;
```

Надо добавить поле в класс StatusModel и настроить отношение через него

```
 private UsersModel usersModel;
```