# Spring. Как создать элемент с внешним ключом с помощью hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Есть 2 таблицы в базе данных

```
create table weight_category(
    id int primary key not null auto_increment,
    name varchar(20) not null,
    weight float not null
);

create table fighter(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    hometown varchar(50) not null,
    height int not null,
    reach float not null,
    rating varchar(15) not null,
    weight_category_id int not null,
    foreign key (weight_category_id) references weight_category(id) on delete cascade on update cascade
);
```

Как создать элемент с внешним ключом с помощью hibernate?

Fighter.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fighter")
public class Fighter {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "hometown")
    private String hometown;

    @Column(name = "height")
    private Integer height;

    @Column(name = "reach")
    private Float reach;

    @Column(name = "rating")
    private String rating;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "weight_category_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private WeightCategory weightCategory;




    public Fighter( String name, String hometown,Integer height,
                    Float reach, String rating) {
        this.name = name;
        this.hometown = hometown;
        this.height = height;
        this.reach = reach;
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public Fighter() {
    }

    public WeightCategory getWeightCategory() {
        return weightCategory;
    }

    public void setWeightCategory(WeightCategory weightCategory) {
        this.weightCategory = weightCategory;
    }


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getHometown() {
        return hometown;
    }

    public void setHometown(String hometown) {
        this.hometown = hometown;
    }

    public Integer getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(Integer height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public Float getReach() {
        return reach;
    }

    public void setReach(Float reach) {
        this.reach = reach;
    }

    public String getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(String rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

}
```

WeightCategory.java

```
package com.example.ufc.database;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "weight_category")
public class WeightCategory {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;


    @Column(name =  "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "weight")
    private Float weight;

    public WeightCategory(){

    }
    public WeightCategory(String name, Float weight){
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public Float getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(Float weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/993198/275232

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fighter")
public class Fighter {

    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "weight_category_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_FIGHTER_WEIGHT_CATEGORY"))
    private WeightCategory weightCategory;

    ...

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "weight_category")
public class WeightCategory {

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "weightCategory")
    private List<Fighter> fighterList;

    ...

}
```