# выбрать user из списка(Thymeleaf)

Tags: spring, rest, thymeleaf

Нужно,чтобы на страницу админа можно было выбрать одного user из списка всех существующих.
На данный момент список пустой

Controler

```
@GetMapping("/admin/user/all")
public String showAllUsers(Model model) {
    List<Users> users = userRpRepository.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("users", users);
    return "redirect:/admin";
}


      @RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String adminPage(Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("teamForm",new TeamForm());
            model.addAttribute("eventForm",new EventForm());
            model.addAttribute("usersForm",new UsersForm());
            model.addAttribute("userTeamForm",new UserTeamForm());
 model.addAttribute("users",new Users());
            return "admin";
        }
```

Users

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class Users {
    @Id
    @Column(name="email",/*unique = true,*/ nullable = false,length = 200)
    String email;

    @Column(name="name",nullable = false,length = 200)
    String name;

    @Column(name="password",nullable = false,length = 128)
    @JsonIgnore 
    String password;
```

admin.html

```
<form>
          <div class="form-group blu-margin">
              <select class="form-control" th:field="${users.name}"  id="addUser">
                  <option value="0">select user</option>
                  <option th:each="user : ${users}" th:value="${user.name}" th:text="${user.name}"></option>

              </select>
          </div>

      </form>
```

Изначально я делал все через формы,но в этот раз,мне кажется этот способ не подойдет, т к в итоге мне надо выбрать одного пользователя, потом одну Team и добавить user к Team, логику я прописал, а вот вывести все на экран не получается.
Или можно дальше с формой работать? 
Я в растерености.

```
public class UserTeamForm {

    private String userName;

    private String teamName;


    public UserTeamForm(String userName, String teamName) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }

    public UserTeamForm() {
    }

гетеры/сеттеры
```

Comment: Вам помог ответ ниже?

Comment: протестирую и отпишусь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Оптимизация кода и исправление ошибок:

#### 1. Два @GetMapping

Вы написали следующее:

```
@GetMapping("/admin/user/all")
public String showAllUsers(Model model) {
    List<Users> users = userRpRepository.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("users", users);
    return "redirect:/admin";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String adminPage(Model model) {
   model.addAttribute("teamForm",new TeamForm());
   model.addAttribute("eventForm",new EventForm());
   model.addAttribute("usersForm",new UsersForm());
   model.addAttribute("userTeamForm",new UserTeamForm());
   model.addAttribute("users",new Users());
return "admin";
}
```

Это надо сократить до такого:

```
@GetMapping("/admin")
public String adminPage(Model model) {
   model.addAttribute("teamForm",new TeamForm());
   model.addAttribute("eventForm",new EventForm());
   model.addAttribute("usersForm",new UsersForm());
   model.addAttribute("userTeamForm",new UserTeamForm());
   model.addAttribute(userRpRepository.findAll());
return "admin";
}
```

#### 2. Неправильное использование th:fields

Так же, у вас ошибка в `<select class="form-control" th:field="${users.name}"  id="addUser">`. Ошибка связана с `th:field="${users.name}"`. `${users}` - это список. чтобы взять любой объект `User` в данном списке, вам надо сделать либо `th:each`, либо указать напрямую на объект с помощью индекса - `${users[10].name}` (как вариант).

Однако данная строчка в вашем коде не нужна, потому что она применятеся только в html-аттрибуте `<input>` или `<textarea>`. `th:field="*"` конвертируется в `id="*" name="*"`

#### 3. Огромное количество сущностей на одной странице

В Вашей форме я вижу много сущностей. Я уверен, что на странице `/admin` нету 2-3 форм. Максимум одна. Советую вам перерасмотреть ваши сущности

#### 4. Оптимизация UserTeamForm

У меня есть сомнения по поводу UserTeamForm... может я не прав. Если вы хотите присваивать пользователей к команде, следует использовать зависимость `@ManyToOne` (Много пользователей у Одной команды), но если у вас один и тот же пользователей фигурирует в нескольких командах - `@ManyToMany` (Много Пользователей во Многих командах). Если есть сложности с зависимостями - посмотрите [данный вопрос/ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/993199/275232)

---

### Решение проблемы с добавлением пользователя к команде

Про добавление Пользователя к Команде:
Как идея, можете сделать список пользователей, в той же форме список команд и в конце кнопку "добавить"

Пример:

```
Выбрать пользователя: -User210-
Выбрать команду: -TeamD-
"Добавить"
```

Код:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group blu-margin">
    <select class="form-control" id="addUser">
      <option value="0">select user</option>
      <option th:each="user : ${users}" th:value="${user.name}" th:text="${user.name}"></option>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control" id="addTeam">
      <option value="0">select team</option>
      <option th:each="team : ${teams}" th:value="${team.name}" th:text="${team.name}"></option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

В таком случае, в форму надо будет передать список юзеров и список команд.

Comment: В таком случае, в форму надо будет передать список юзеров и список команд. 
вы имеете ввиду,что в надо добавить в UserTeamForm
List<Users> users
List<Team> teams
?

Comment: Я ведь ее(UserTeamForm) не использую, если посмотреть предложенный вами код

Comment: Я бы убрал сущность UserTeamForm - это лишняя сущность. Лучше добавьте в User-сущность и Team-сущность маппинг друг на друга. Используйте для этого аннотации `@OneToMany` или `@ManyToMany` для вашего случая

Comment: Посмотрите [данный ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/993199/275232)