# Hibernate ManyToOne OneToMany каскадное удаление зависимых сущностей

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

В проекте существуют сущности Account и Services (абстрактный). У Services есть дочерний класс Deposit.
Код класса Account:

```
@Entity
public class Account {
  private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(Account.class);

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;
  @Column
  private double amount;
  @Column
  private AccountType type;
  @Column(name = "date_start")
  private Date dateStart;
  @Column(name = "date_end")
  private Date dateEnd;
  @Column(name = "in_rate")
  private short inRate;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
  private Client client;
...
```

Код класса Services:

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract public class Services {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  protected long id;
  @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "from_acc_id")
  protected Account fromAcc;
...
```

У Deposit в дополнение есть поле amount, но это не столь важно. При попытке удаления экземпляра Account, на которую есть ссылки из Deposit, выдаёт ошибку:

```
2020-03-13 13:29:51 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:131 - ОШИБКА: UPDATE или DELETE в таблице "account" нарушает ограничение внешнего ключа "fk8qcea1frw0og19kft1ltq9kf9" таблицы "deposit"
Подробности: На ключ (id)=(1) всё ещё есть ссылки в таблице "deposit".
```

Как настроить каскадное удаление так, чтобы при удалении записи account записи из deposit удалялись автоматически?

Comment: Рассмотрите данный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/993198/275232

Comment: у класса Account должно быть поле `@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE) List<Services> services...`

Comment: @MrFylypenko ваш вариант выдаёт ошибку при записи:
`2020-03-14 11:42:35 ERROR HibernateDataProvider:44 - org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: ru.sfedu.terApp.models.mappedSuperclass.Account.services[ru.sfedu.terApp.models.mappedSuperclass.Services]`
Если сменить тип List на Deposit, запись отрабатывает, но удаление выдаёт всё то же.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем итоге помогла аннотация @OnDelete. Класс Account не изменял. Код Services:

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract public class Services {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  protected long id;
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
  @JoinColumn(name = "from_account_id")
  @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
  protected Account fromAcc;
...
```