# Не подвязывается ManyToMany

Tags: java, hibernate

В своем учебном проекте хочу попробовать связь ManyToMany. Когда пытаюсь создать объект Project через PostMan, cам объект создаётся, но Set сотрудников не сетится. Классы и запрос к postman ниже:

Postman body:

```
{
    "name" : "project",
    "employees": [
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Terminator",
        "sex": "OTHER",
        "position": "Robot",
        "salary": 54363,
        "dateOfHire": "2015-07-04"
    }
    ]
}
```

Project.java:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "employee_project",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "project_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")})
    private Set<Employee> employees;
}
```

Employee.java:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")

public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "employees", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Project> projects;
}
```

Comment: Рассмотрите данный вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/993198/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9-onetomany-onetoone-manytomany-manytoone-hibernate/993199#993199

Comment: Должен Вам помочь)