# hibernate, onetoone

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

есть класс Билет, в нем поля типа Город и Страна
при создании билета нужно выдернуть из базы эти город и страну
однако при попытке записи в базу ругается, что нужно сначала сохранить город и страну
как правильно описать данные поля? Если выставить cascade, то тогда он попытается сохранить в базу город и страну, и опять ругнется только теперь на то что нарушено условие уникальности

```
public class FlightTicket implements Comparable<FlightTicket> {

    @OneToOne
    private City cityOfDepart;
    @OneToOne
    private Country countryOfDepart;
}
```

Comment: как объяснить hibernate что не нужно сохранять эти поля еще раз

Comment: Как я помню из статей, то @OneToOne используется очень редко, а тут Вы используете его 2 раза в одном entity. Возможно, вы хотели использовать зависимость OneToMany (т.к. один и город может фигурировать в нескольких «билетах»)

Comment: То же самое касается Country: в билете вы указываете ОДНУ страну (не список стран), но страна может фигурировать во МНОЖЕСТВЕ билетов => OneToMany

Comment: Рассмотрите примеры в [данном вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/993198/275232). Возможно, Вы найдете там ответ на ваш вопрос.

Comment: с проблемой разобрался, была проблема в том, что я сначала вытаскивал страну из таблицы не целиком, без id, после того как переделал метод репозитория все заработало

Answer (score 0):

с проблемой разобрался, была проблема в том, что я сначала вытаскивал страну из таблицы не целиком, без id, после того как переделал метод репозитория все заработало