# чем заменить String при использованни hibernate связей?

Tags: java, база-данных, spring, hibernate

Пытаюсь добавить связи в hibernate и мне нужно что бы поле на которое ссылается другое поле было String'ом  но код не компилируется так, есть какие то обходы этой проблемы?

кстать если что вот текст ошибки:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on ua.prin.rom.entity.ShortLink.longLink references an unknown entity: java.lang.String

```
package ua.prin.rom.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
public class ShortLink {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private String longLink;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String shortlink;
```

Comment: а если 2 поля сделать в коде на одно в таблице?

Answer (score 0):

Видимо поле должно быть не типа String, а другого класса с аннотацией @Entity.
Как например у класса Person поле класса Address.

Comment: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/993198/261757] по этой теме

Answer (score 0):

У вас в ошибке ясно прописано `ua.prin.rom.entity.ShortLink.longLink references an unknown entity`, вы указали связь, но не указали на что ссылаетесь. Вам необходимо добавить `@JoinColumn`, а с обратной стороны `mappedBy`

Comment: Да, щас он как добавит `mappedBy` в классе `String`

Comment: @FirstSin, именно поэтому человек может сделать вывод, что он пишет что-то не так и обратиться к документации снова